# Referring to a specific "bisabuelo(a)"

Tags: selección-de-palabras

When talking about grandparents, you can add "materno(a)/paterno(a)" to refer to a specific one. Example: *abuelo paterno*.

Is there a way to refer to a particular "bisabuelo(a)" (great-grandparent)?

Comment: Is there any way to refer to a particular great-grandparent in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way. One way I've heard is:

> El abuelo paterno de la madre de Juan

Comment: Así lo veo yo. Hace muchos años me planteé esta misma cuestión y jamás oí ni leí nada que me dijera que existían tales palabras.